# Timeout with TransactionScopeOptions.Suppress

Tags: c#, transactions, nservicebus

Found this line in an application I just took over, and it doesn't make much sense.

`using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress, new TimeSpan(1,0,0))) {`

This occurs immediately inside a nservicebus message handler method and covers the entire handler.

It appears to be trying to suppress the ambient transaction and after an hour aborting. What happens when the timeout expires? I assume this is just a combination of options that doesn't mean anything reasonable. But what does it result in happening?

Answer (score 1):

`Suppress` means that the ambient transaction is not used; and that, in affect, the operations within the scope are not performed in a transaction.  This allows you to execute operations outside of the current transaction without being affected by that transaction.  e.g.:

```
using(var trans = new TransactionScope())
{
   // do operations within transaction
   using(var unscoped = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
   {
      // do "immediate" operations
   }
   // do operations within transaction
   // NOTE: No trans.Complete() called
}

// operations performed within `unscoped` are not rolled back.
```

I'm not really sure if the timeout really makes any sense with `Suppress`

Comment: typo - within unscoped, rather than within scoped.  Also, the dirty trick with "forgetting" to call Complete could perhaps be better explained in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

> If the scope is instantiated with Suppress, it never takes part in a transaction, regardless of whether an ambient transaction is present. A scope instantiated with this value always have null as its ambient transaction.

The timeout setting has no effect with `Suppress`.  The two can be combined only because the set of `TransactionScope` constructors is static and it cannot prevent the combination from being specified.

For a "nested" transaction scope, specifying the timeout can reduce, but not increase, the timeout on the ambient transaction.

In contrast, the `TransactionScope` instantiated with `Suppress` never joins any ambient transaction, nor forms a new one, and therefore nobody's transaction timeout is ever affected.